# What is this sign?

Tags: kanji

[image][image]

When i use Google Translate on my phone it translate it as either - or !
But my problem is that it looks nothing like the one in the the various Manga´s and such where i see it.
So anyone know what this Kanji sign, is supposed to look like if it was written on a keyboard?

Comment: Do you have a picture with it in context? With just a picture of a straight line it's impossible to know what it is.

Comment: added an extra picture its more that it looks a little like the number 1 where the upper line is turned upwards instead of downwards.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Donpu

Answer (score 1):

That's just the katakana ー which extends the vowel sound. The word is ボール.
If you're not familiar with this character it's time to revise katakana.